# Azure Service Fabric Actors Reentrancy with Services

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When using stateful services and actors in service fabric, the documentation states that actors have an reentrancy policy allowing actors to go from ActorA to AcotrB and back to ActorA in one call context chain. [As described here here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-reentrancy/)

But how does this interact with services? Eg. can i do something like: Service1 > Actor1 > Service2 > Actor2 > Service1 > Actor1 ...? Or will the call context be lost when contacting a service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-entrancy only applies between actors. In your example, the second invocation from Service1 to Actor1 will block and eventually time out.